# Exchange 2010 Room Mailbox Calendar Permissions

Tags: exchange-2010, outlook-2007, outlook-2010

Exchange 2010 sp2

Outlook 2007/2010

Server 2008

I have managed to set up several room mailboxes in exchange, people are able to book the rooms and they get a response from the exchange server. this is brilliant.

however users are unable to view the calendar of the room mailbox to see what times are available, in a ideal world I would like users to only see if the room is free or not.

I dont want users to see the details of the meeting (title, description etc)

I have been trying to do this using the following command

**Add-MailboxFolderPermission -Identity meetingroom -User "Usergroup" -AccessRights AvailabilityOnly -DomainController AD-Server**

This throws the following error

**Specified argument was out of the range of valid values.
Parameter name: memberRights
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (meetingroom:MailboxFolderIdParameter) [Add-MailboxFolderPermission], Argum
   entOutOfRangeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CBC6516F,Microsoft.Exchange.Management.StoreTasks.AddMailboxFolderPermission**

Any help on the situation would be brilliant, i have been trying to get this done for a couple of days and im going around in circles.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that by default you get this behaviour if you use the scheduling assistant in Outlook to view the room availability, rather than trying to alter mailbox permissions to allow users to view the mailbox directly. I could be wrong, but that's how we use it.

Comment: Bryan,This is correct and i got this working but users have voiced that they would also like to see the calander of the room at all times. although believe the room list has stopped working i noticed the other day it was working before we moved offices but after the move the room list no longer appears in the drop down in the scheduling assistant in outlook 2010.

Answer (score 3):

It looks like you are specifying just the mailbox "meetingroom" and not it's calendar folder.  The command would look something like this:

```
Add-MailboxFolderPermission -Identity meetingroom:\Calendar -User "Usergroup" -AccessRights AvailabilityOnly -DomainController AD-Server
```

Notice the ":\Calendar" added onto the Identity.

Comment: i will update when i have tried this,

Comment: Phil is right, see here as well: http://blog.powershell.no/2010/09/20/managing-calendar-permissions-in-exchange-server-2010/